# Who is this famous person?

Tags: wordplay

Replace each of the five lines below with a word, phrase, etc. of similar meaning. Put the results together to spell (phonetically, anyway) a famous person's name in five syllables. Who is it?

Old man
Defeat
Harvest
Puzzler's utterance
BF, GF, DW or DH

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This might be the famous artist formerly known as

> Father (Old man)
>  Sudden hindrance suffered (Defeat)
>  To collect crops (Harvest)
>  Exclamation for flashes of insight (Puzzler's utterance)
>  Abbreviation for "Significant Other" (boyfriend, girlfriend, dear wife or dear husband),

or

> **[Pa-Blow-Pick-Ah!-SO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pablo_Picasso)**

for short.